# What is the correct way to configure Digest Authentication on the Wildfly Application Server

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have configure the Digest Auhentication on Wildfly 10 how describe in

[Security by WildFly with login-module "UsersRoles"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677030/security-by-wildfly-with-login-module-usersroles)

But this configuration don't works properly.
I have don't found any usefully helps on Jboss wikis.

Does anyone know how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration from

[Security by WildFly with login-module "UsersRoles"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677030/security-by-wildfly-with-login-module-usersroles)

includes an error. This package is wrong:

`<module-option name="storeDigestCallback" value="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RFC2617Digest"/>`

The corret package is:

`<module-option name="storeDigestCallback" value="org.jboss.security.auth.callback.RFC2617Digest"/>`

The **callback** is here the key-word.
After change of the content of this module-option the authentication works!